# Reading from application.properties and replace dynamic parameters

Tags: java, dynamic, parameters, application.properties

How can my Spring Boot application read application.properties values with a parameter(s) like it's possible for ResourceBundles using MessageFormat?

For instance, if I have in `application.properties`:

```
crm.api.url.contact=/contacts/v1/contact/vid/{0}/profile
```

What's the best way to replace thee placeholder `{0}` with a real value (an ID in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no better way, I solved my problem using `MessageFormat` in conjunction with `@Value`:

```
// Autowired via constructor based injection
private final String MY_API_KEY;
private final String MY_API_URL_BASE;
private final String MY_API_URL_CONTACT;

MessageFormat.format(MY_API_URL_BASE + MY_API_URL_CONTACT + MY_API_URL_API_KEY_PARAM + MY_API_KEY, contactId.toString()), String.class);
```